# Clear the login, delete the session, and redirect back to the login page using isPostBack - PHP

Tags: php

I've spent a lot of time today researching this site for my solution but I have had no luck.  I'm currently trying to learn php and working on my second project. I can only use PHP. I originally had my delete session and redirect in a separate logout.php file. This was working but then I found out that I can't do this. I've been instructed that I need to "clear the login, delete the session, and redirect back to the login page" and do this within an isPostBack in the results.php file. After a lot of research today I thought I was understanding how to do this but I can't get it to work. Hoping I can get some help.

```html
<?php
session_start();
//require_once('cookies.php');

$isPostBack = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'submit');

//this is where I need to do the isPostBack for user clicking "logout".
if ($isPostBack) {
    // clear ALL session data from memory
    // clean up the session and remove the session ID.
    // redirect to index.php
        endSession();
        session_destroy();
        header("Location: index.php");
} else {
   // user did not click logout doNothing();
}

?>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Results</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="">
</head>
<body>
<form action="results.php">
    <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Logout" />
</form>
<section>
    <?php
    foreach($_SESSION['answers'] as $answer){
        echo "<p>$answer</p>";
    }
    ?>
</section>
</body>
```

Comment: Is a postback still a postback if you are using GET instead of POST, one wonders :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try to provide name attribute

```
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Logout" name="logout"/>
```

and use only logout variable in place of submit or provide two different fields

```
$isPostBack = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'submit');
$isPostBack = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'logout');
```

Comment: Thank you.. I had just edited my original post before seeing your response. I noticed my mistake, where I wasn't giving the isPostBack a matching variable name.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have found my solution.  I needed to give the isPostBack variable a name that matched the name given to the logout button. I also needed to include !==NULL after the isPostBack. I changed endSession(); to $_SESSION = array();  According to my research, endSession(); "removes all session variables".  It seems to be working as it should now.  Here is my edited code.

```html
<?php
session_start();

$isPostBack = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'submit')!==NUll;

//this is where I need to do the isPostBack for user clicking "logout".
if ($isPostBack) {
    // clear ALL session data from memory
    // clean up the session and remove the session ID.
    // redirect to index.php
        $_SESSION = array();
        session_destroy();
        header("Location: index.php");
} else {
   // user did not click logout doNothing();
}

?>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Results</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="">
</head>
<body>
<form action="results.php">
    <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Logout" />
</form>
<section>
    <?php
    foreach($_SESSION['answers'] as $answer){
        echo "<p> $answer</p>";
    }
    ?>
</section>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to remove se particular session values you can use unset()

```
unset ($_SESSION['userid'])
```